# PS scricpt to Create AD Accounts from csv file

Tags: powershell, server, active-directory, import-csv

I can't create Second Account with this same Name (CN) and I need to change DistinguishedName in script. Please Help I am beginner in PS.

Code:

```
$list = Import-Csv C:\it\users.csv 

foreach ($user in $list) {
    $Attributes = @{
        Enabled                   = $True
        ChangePasswordAtLogon     = $True
        Path                      = "OU=Agents,OU=PL,DC=emea,DC=tpg,DC=ads"
        Name                      = "$($user.First) $($user.Last)" + "blabla"
        Description               = $user.Description
        UserPrincipalName         = $user.UserPrincipalName
        SamAccountName            = $user.SamAccountName
        GivenName                 = $user.First
        Surname                   = $user.Last
        DisplayName               = $user.DisplayName
        Title                     = $user.Title
        Department                = $user.Department
        Street                    = $user.Street
        City                      = $user.City
        PostalCode                = $user.PostalCode
        Country                   = $user.Country
        Company                   = $user.Company
        AccountPassword           = $user.AccountPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
        
    }
    $ADUser = New-ADUser @Attributes
}
```

I have one Error now
Errors:

```
New-ADUser : An attempt was made to add an object to the directory with a name that is already in use
At C:\it\ps1.ps1:24 char:15
+     $ADUser = New-ADUser @Attributes
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=Grzegorz Pie...a,DC=tpg,DC=ads:String) [New-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8305,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser
```

Comment: Display name is empty.

Comment: What ? Where ? hmm ?

Comment: What? Display name was empty. Where? Display name property. Hmm? You edited and corrected the issue. The error your getting now is pretty self explanatory, it says there's a user with that name already there.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $list = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\it\users.csv'  #ścieżka do pliku

foreach ($user in $list) {
    $param = @{
        
       
        Enabled                   = $True
        ChangePasswordAtLogon     = $True
        Path                      = "OU=Agents,OU=PL,DC=emea,DC=NO,DC=ads" 

        #Tutaj dane są pobierane z pliku
        DisplayName               = $user.DisplayName
        Name                      = "$($User.First) $($User.Last)" + " Recruiter" 
        Description               = $user.Description
        UserPrincipalName         = $user.UserPrincipalName
        SamAccountName            = $user.SamAccountName
        GivenName                 = $user.First
        Surname                   = $user.Last
        AccountPassword           = $user.AccountPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
        Title = $user.Title
        Department = $user.Department
        Company = $user.Company
        City = $user.City
        StreetAddress = $user.StreetAddress
        Country = $user.Country #w postaci PL
        PostalCode = $user.PostalCode
 

           
    }
    
    New-ADUser @param
    
    }
```

Correct code for same First and Last Name, but different Display Name